# Binary Search Tree Deletion Problem When creating the Node class with left node first

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am creating a binary search tree in C++ using classes. When I write the left address first as in the example, deletion is not working correctly for random nodes.

Example:

```
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        Node(){ data=0; right=left=NULL;};
        Node(int x){ data=x; right=left=NULL;};
        bool is_leaf(){ return (left==NULL && right==NULL);
        }
};

class BST{
    
    private:
        Node* root;
        Node * _del(int x,Node* n);
                void _insert_rec(int x,Node*n);
    public:
        BST(){ root=NULL; };
        void insert_rec(int x);
        void print();
        void del(int x);

};

void BST::del(int x)
{
    root = _del(x,root);
}

Node * BST::_del(int x,Node* n)
{
    if(!n)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        if(x<n->data)
            n->left = _del(x,n->left);
        else if(x>n->data)
            n->right = _del(x,n->right);
        else
        {
            if(n->is_leaf())
            {
                delete n;
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!n->right)
                {
                    delete n;
                    return n->left;
                }
                else if (!n->left)
                {
                    delete n;
                    return n->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    int enb = _max_value(n->left);
                    n->data = enb;
                    n->left = _del(enb,n->left);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}

void BST::insert_rec(int x)
{
    root = _insert_rec(x,root);
}

Node * BST::_insert_rec(int x,Node* r)
{
    if(!r)
        return new Node(x);
    else
    {
        if(x>r->data)
            r->right = _insert_rec(x,r->right);
        else
            r->left = _insert_rec(x,r->left);
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    BST *bst = new BST();
    bst->insert_rec(50);
    bst->insert_rec(100);
    bst->insert_rec(20);
    bst->insert_rec(10);
    bst->insert_rec(70);


    bst->print();
    bst->del(100);
    cout<<endl;
    bst->print();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to delete `100` or `50`, the code doesn't work.
If I change the `Node` class as below everything works fine:

```
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        
        Node* right;  // Only changed the order of the addresses.
        Node* left;
        
        Node(){ data=0; right=left=NULL;};
        Node(int x){ data=x; right=left=NULL;};
        bool is_leaf(){ return (left==NULL && right==NULL);
        }
};
```

Changed the order of the addresses. But I want to understand the reason behind this situation.

Comment: `delete n; return n->left;` is wrong, you have to store `n->left` before deleting `n`. Also your code does not compile.

Comment: Undefined behaviour can be pretty unpredictable. Sometimes it can even seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here

```
            if(!n->right)
            {
                delete n;
                return n->left;
            }
```

You are deleting the pointer `n` and then dereferencing it. You should use a temporary variable

```
            if(!n->right)
            {
                Node* tmp = n->left;
                delete n;
                return tmp;
            }
```

With that change (in two places) it seems to work for me.